# multiple blacklist files shorewall

Tags: blacklist, shorewall

I have been blocking by ip with shorewall and the blacklist file. I have decided to block a few country entirely and the blacklist file is huge!

So my question is this:

Is it possible to have multiple blacklist files for shorewall? 
If so how would you go about loading them?

If not, is there another alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.shorewall.net/ipsets.html), you could save your "adresses non gratae" as ipsets and reference these sets from your blacklist file.

You'd need to write a script though that feeds the list into shorewall though at least once.

Note that this requires at least shorewall 4.4.0.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Im going to give this a shoot. I'm fairly new to shorewall and iptables so this will give me some added experience working with both.

Answer (score 0):

Under recent shorewall versions, all configuration files accept the INCLUDE directive, so you could set up those files and include them from the master blacklist file.